# Can I develop an Android web app using Webkit 537.36 on Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.4

Tags: android, webkit

I am looking into creating a web app on Android, and have a question about the version of Webkit. The device I'm looking at runs on Android 4.0.4 which lists the User Agent's WebKit as version 534.30. I checked this on http://whatsmyuseragent.com/

I have installed Chrome and when I go to the same site it lists the User Agent WebKit as version 537.36. So it looks like Chrome embeds the most recent version

So my question is can I use the most recent WebKit for my Webview instead of the native one in the OS. On the Android Developer website it says:

> If you serve content to your WebView based on the user agent, you
>   should to be aware of the user agent string has changed slightly and
>   now includes the Chrome version:

Does this mean I can use the same WebKit version that Chrome is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

1. The change you mentioned only concerns the user agent string. (That is, what the browser claims itself to be.)
2. The change only happened in Android 4.4. Starting with Android 4.4, the WebView is actually based on Google's Chromium code, whereas before it was before it was based on Apple's WebKit code.

However, you can bundle an own version of the WebKit/Blink engine with your app. Try e.g. [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/).